# How to make so that the function run only one time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Script number one performed for each of a given set of elements DOM, append to the first element of the DOM script number two.

**Script number one:**

```
function ptmedia(){
$('.ptmcss').eq(0).html('<div class="ptmcss"></div>')
.append('<div class="append"><script type="text/javascript" src="script2.js"></script></div>');
$('.spbin').each(function(){
if($(this).children().attr('class').indexOf('ptmd')!==-1){
$(this).addClass('ptmedia');ptmedia();}
```

Script number two does cross domain query, the fulfillment of which performs the specified function **(z)**. 
**Script number two**:

```
$.getJSON('http://example.com?callback=?',function(z){alert(z.query+'Some text');}
```

Due to the fact that the script is the number one multiple times, the function **(z)** holds an equal number of times. How to make so that the function **(z)** run only one time?
Thank's for any help!

Comment: Why are you appending the script like this? Why don't you just include the script in the page, put the `$.getJSON` code in a function, and call the function when you need it?

Comment: The RunOnce tag doesn't fit here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the script has been appended already, if yes, don't allow it to run.

```
if( $('.append').length <= 1 ) {
    $.getJSON('http://example.com?callback=?',function(z){alert(z.query+'Some text');}
}
```

Comment: Still occur several times (((

Comment: Should be if( !$('.append').length)

Comment: If length is 0, the script hasn't been appended at all.
@Aleksov: I don't get how your two scripts work together. Normally, script2 is only added once since you do an '.eq(0)'

Comment: interestingly, the `$('. append')` and attached script append once to the DOM, but added the script executed multiple times

Comment: Do you have a link you can provide?

Comment: Ok! Thank's то all! I do something like this: `$.getJSON('http://example.com?callback=?',function(z){if( $('#upddia').length <= 0 ) {
 
 //some code
 var g=$('<div id="upddia"></div>').appendTo('.append').eq(0);
 //some code
 
 }}`
And it works!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the jquery **.one** statement?  http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: nice one. I wasn't aware of such function in jQuery

Comment: Yes, I have studied it, but I did not understand how to apply it in my case

Comment: In all likelihood, in my case I need to stop the $.getJSON and with it all the nested function

Comment: Is this a question or an answer? How would you apply jQuery's `.one()` to this situation?

Comment: It was a suggestion, and I'm sorry for my English. Thank you very much for your active participation in solving my problem, your opinion is very important to me and I really appreciate it very much! At the moment, the problem is solved, many thanks and bow!